# SQL query two tables with a condition in the child table and record not exist in child

Tags: mysql, sql, select

i have two tables (mysql):
channels:

| uid | time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 23423 |
| 2 | 52422 |
| 3 | 23423 |
| 4 | 42342 |
| NULL | 345 |

users:

| uid | id | gid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sam1 | 1 |
| 2 | sam2 | 2 |
| 3 | sam2 | 2 |
| 4 | sam2 | 3 |

i want to select all channel for users with gid=1 and gid=2 and for not existing users

i run query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.gid, c.time
FROM channels c 
LEFT JOIN users u ON (u.uid=c.uid) 
WHERE (u.gid IN (NULL,'1', '2'))
```

and have

| uid | gid | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 23423 |
| 2 | 2 | 52422 |
| 3 | 2 | 23423 |

how to select a channel for a non-existent user ?
i want to get the following result:

| uid | gid | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 23423 |
| 2 | 2 | 52422 |
| 3 | 2 | 23423 |
| NULL | NULL | 345 |

Answer (score 2):

Use `IS NULL` to check for null values:

```sql
SELECT u.id, u.gid, c.time
FROM channels c 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.uid = c.uid
WHERE u.gid IN (1, 2) OR c.uid IS NULL;
```